# I forked a project, someone else contribute to the project, too. How could I get his/her change?

Tags: git, github

I forked one project in Github.

Then someone else contribute to this project, and been merged. How could I get the latest version ?

`git pull` is not working I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [`sync with upstream`](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) if the contribution has been merged into the project you forked from.

Comment: @liuzhidong, simply `push` your changes after merging them locally.